# Is every closed subset of finite measure contained in an open subset of finite measure?

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory, borel-sets

Could someone will verify my statement: For every locally finite Borel measure on metric space and closed set $F$ with finite measure, there exists open set $U$ such that $F \subset U$ and $U$ has finite measure ?

Comment: What do you call "locally finite"? This terminology is usually used in locally compact spaces, where it equivalently means (a) finite on compact subsets (b) each point has a neighborhood of finite measure. The terminology would rather naturally mean (b), but it's better specify.

Comment: I mean finite on bounded subsets

Comment: On bounded subsets? this is not standard... in the answer you accepted, the whole space is bounded, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, it's bounded by what ?

Comment: The distance is uniformly bounded by $1$. Since the whole space has infinite measure, this is not "locally finite" in your sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not in general.

My metric space is the disjoint union of uncountably many copies of $\mathbb R$.
$$X = \bigsqcup_{t \in T}  X_t$$
where $T$ is uncountable and $X_t = \mathbb R$ for all $t$.  The metric: two points in the same $X_t$ have distance $\min(|x-y|,1)$, two points in different $X_t$ have distance $1$.
My measure is Lebesgue measure $\mu_t$ on each copy $X_t$ of $\mathbb R$.  So for a subset $E \subseteq X$ we can write $E = \bigsqcup_{t \in T} E_t$ where $E_t \subseteq \mathbb R$, and its measure is $$\mu(E) = \sum_{t \in T}\mu_t(E_t).$$

This measure is locally finite.  Any point in $X$ lies in exactly one set $X_t$ and the open ball of radius $1/2$ centered there has measure $1$.

But your finiteness property fails.  Let the closed set be $$F = \bigsqcup_{t \in T} F_t$$ where $F_t = \{0\}$ for all $t$.  Then $\mu(F) = 0$.  Let $G \supseteq F$ be an open set.  I claim $\mu(G) = +\infty$.  Indeed, $$G = \bigsqcup_{t \in T} G_t$$ where for all $t$, the set $G_t$ is an open neighborhood of $\{0\}$.  So $\mu(G_t) > 0$ for all $t$.  And $\mu(G) = \sum \mu_t(G_t)$ is an uncountable sum of positive numbers.  So $\mu(G) = +\infty$.

Comment: To get your conclusion you could assume the metric space is separable.  Or you could assume your closed set is $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: Don't you want copies of $(0,1)$ instead? Otherwise the triangle inequality fails.

Comment: Good point.  Or use metric $d(x,y) = \min(|x-y|,1)$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ok, it's a simple counterexample in some way, but not obvious. Thank you for that @GeraldEdgar

Comment: In fact, I could assume $\tau$-additivity of measure, but separability of metric space is too strong for my contemplations